# Azure Functions Service Bus output binding - message properties

Tags: java, azure-functions, azureservicebus

```
@FunctionName("MyFunction")
public void run(
        @ServiceBusQueueTrigger(name = "message", queueName = "Input", connection = "connStr") String message,
        @BindingName("UserProperties") Map<String, Object> properties,
        @ServiceBusQueueOutput(name = "result", queueName = "Output", connection = "connStr") OutputBinding<String> result,
        ExecutionContext context
) {
    // do something
    result.setValue("output msg");
}
```

In the **input binding** I can easily fetch the message properties using the `@BindingName("UserProperties")` annotation, like in the code above. Is there a similar way to customize the properties of the **output binding** message?

I could use the Service Bus SDK to send the message with custom properties at the end of my function, but I'd really prefer to do it the binding way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't supported for non-C# languages. You will have to instead use the Azure Service Bus SDK directly.

Comment: Such a shame. Thanks for the answer anyway.